# Convert subqueries to Joins

Tags: sql, join, subquery, impala

I am trying to improve my query performance, since I am dealing with Big Data. (Many TB's of data)
I am working on Impala.

The query I used is mentioned as below. This is in the form of subquery. Not sure how I can optimize it.
May be JOINS. If yes, I am not able to convert this subquery to JOINS.

Please suggest on how to convert this subquery to JOINS. I need to improve my query performance

```
select mytable.id,group_concat(mytable.acqid) as 'acqid',group_concat(mytable.address) as 'address'
from (select myinnertable.id, case when myinnertable.mykey = 'AcqId' then myinnertable.myvalue end as 'acqid',
             case when myinnertable.mykey = 'Address' then myinnertable.myvalue end as 'address'
      from (select id,mykey,myvalue
            from table1
            where table1.date_col BETWEEN '2021-05-02' and '2021-05-19' and mykey!='velList'
           ) myinnertable
     ) mytable
group by mytable.id;
```

Comment: Your query only refers to one table.  What kind of `JOIN` might you be thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing can be simplified without the nested context.  As Gordon pointed out, you are only using 1 table but making 3 passes through the results.  I would ensure it has an index on `(date_col, id, mykey)` to help optimize pulling data.

```
select 
        t1.id, 
        group_concat( case when t1.mykey = 'AcqId' 
                        then t1.myvalue end ) acqid,
        group_concat( case when t1.mykey = 'Address' 
                        then t1.myvalue end ) address
    from 
        table1 t1
    where 
            t1.date_col BETWEEN '2021-05-02' and '2021-05-19' 
        and t1.mykey != 'velList' 
    group by 
        t1.id;
```